# Make Command is taking too long

Tags: ubuntu, make, node.js

I am trying to install NodeJS on Ubuntu, following http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs. When I ran `make` command, its taking too too long, printing lines after lines on screen. Is there any alternative to install NodeJS quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the package [`nodejs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nodejs) from Ubuntu's repository.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

In case you need a specific or more recent version that provided there, I recommend reading answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214474/how-to-keep-up-with-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-in-ubuntu-ppa-compiling) instead.

Another alternative is to build it on a faster machine, running the same software versions (Ubuntu, libraries installed, etc.) as on your machine you want to deploy on. Then copy over all the files and only run the `install` target using `make`.

Comment: "E: Couldn't find package nodejs", getting this.

Comment: It has been in Ubuntu since Natty (11.04) in the ``universe`` repository as can be seen from the link I posted. Check that you are running a recent version of Ubuntu and have the universe repository enabled (check 'Software Sources' for GUI systems or ``/etc/apt/sources.list`` for a headless machine).

Comment: Anyway to handle this in Ubuntu 9.10 ??? My problem has been solved, I am just curious and wanna learn more.

Comment: @Rizwan Ubuntu 9.10 has been EOL'd since April 2011. I recommend you to upgrade instead. It will be hard to upgrade all the libraries node.js is depending on.